# Loop columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through columns.

I'm not sure about the range. Should I use normal range where we have the alphabets as columns?

I tried different codes. For example:

```
Sub copytest()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim j As Integer, i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open ("D:\test\COMP.xlsx")

i = 3

For j = 3 To 14

    Sheets("Compliance").Range(Cells(18, i), Cells(30, i)).Copy
    Windows("KP.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("MOH").Range(Cells(12, j), Cells(24, j)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False

    i = i + 2

Next j

x.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use numbers for columns. Let's say you want to loop through first 5 rows and first 5 columns then you can write it as

```
For i = 1 To 5 '<~~~ Rows
    For j = 1 To 5 '<~~~ Columns
        With ThisWorkbook.Cells(i, j)
            '~~> Do something
        End With
    Next j
Next i
```

In Excel 2013, the last column is XFD which is column number 16384.

```
A - 1
B - 2
C - 3 
.
.
and so on...
XFD - 16384
```

If you would like to loop using Column Names then you can use it as such

```
Dim ColName As String

For i = 1 To 5 '<~~~ Rows
    For j = 1 To 5 '<~~~ Columns
       ColName  = Split(Cells(, j).Address, "$")(1)
        With ThisWorkbook.Range(ColName & i)
            '~~> Do something
        End With
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: LOL - This suddenly brought back some very old memories.  I was thinking "Argh - i & j as variables - why don't we use r & c, or perhaps y & x" - which then made me think "why DO we so often use i as the first loop variable and j as the second one?" and remembered it is because FORTRAN used to default to using floating point types for variable names starting with A to H or O to Z (I think that was the ranges) and integer type for variable names starting with I to N.  Sigh, those were the good old days.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative for looping though columns is a `For Each cell in my1RowRange` loop, where

- `cell` is a single-cell `Range` object that loops over `my1RowRange` `Range`
- `my1RowRange` must be a 1-Row `Range`

besides that, your code has some major flaws:

- your range references use *simple* `Cells(...)` reference without any explicit `worksheet` and `workbook` reference before them

  so that they keep referencing the *active* `worksheet` in the *active* `workbook`

  and this is no good since during your loop you only seem to keep changing the *right* workbook while you're actually only changing it once at the beginning (`Windows("KP.xlsm").Activate`) and then it always remains the only referenced workbook
- avoid `Activate`/`ActiveXXX` (as well as `Select`/`Selection`) coding, since

  - it's error prone, like it proved to be right here, since it most likely lead you to loose control over actual *active* workbook/worksheet
  - it's time consuming and gets screen flickerings

so consider the following refactoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copytest()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim compWb As Workbook
    Dim compRng As Range, cell As Range

    Set compWb = Workbooks.Open "D:\test\COMP.xlsx" '<--| set the workbook to open to a specific variable of 'Workbook' type

    With compWb.Worksheets("Compliance") '<--| refer to "compliance" worksheet of the "right" (you're explicitly referencing it!) workbook
        Set compRng = .Range(.Cells(18, 3), .Cells(30, 3)) '<--| set the "source" range: all the dots means we're referencing the object after the last "With" statement
    End With

    i = 3
    With Workbooks("KP.xlsm").Worksheets("MOH") '<--| refer to "MOH" worksheet of "KP" workbook
        For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(12, 3), .Cells(12, 14)) '<--| loop through cells of a 1-row range of the referenced worksheet: this means looping through columns!
            cell.Resize(13).Value = compRng.Offset(, i - 3).Value '<--| paste values while offsetting the "souce" range columns (first iteration with offset=0)
            i = i + 2
        Next cell
    End With

    compWb.Close '<--| close the opened workbook
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Columns()

Dim rng As Range
Dim col As Range
Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'make shure its in the correct sheet

Set rng = Range("C3:G6") 'select the range of the whole table


For Each col In rng.Columns 'this performs a tasks column by column
    'Do Something
    col.Select
    Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    'end something

Next col 'move to next column

End Sub
```